# Win Forms Application and Windows Service in one Project

Tags: c#, winforms, service

I'm trying to create a windows service that also has a winforms application with it to update settings using a gui. I'm saving the settings to the default settings area as application settings. So each element needs access to the settings, eg from the service and from the winforms.

I just want to know do i set it up as 2 separate projects inside a solution in Visual Studio, or 1 project and add all the classes to it. It's confusing the heck out of me.

I initially read that you create the win forms application then add the service to that with an installer. I just don't fully understand the concept. I come from a PHP background so this is quite foreign to me. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One solution. Two projects.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart so that would still allow me to share the application settings across both projects?

Comment: Just remember that application settings are user-scoped, so if your service runs under a non-interactive user account (usually Local Service or Network Service) it will not be able to see any settings you configure using your Win Forms app (which would run as the currently logged-in user).

Comment: @BradleySmith If i have my settings set to scope = Application am i still able to access them from the other project?

Comment: Application-scoped settings can be accessed from any user account, but they are also read-only.